# Solving equations involving x↑↑3

Tags: lambert-w

How would you solve for x in the equation: 
$$x^{x^x}=2$$
using the Lambert W-Function?

Comment: what makes you think you can?

Comment: Mathematica input: `Solve[x^x^x == 2, x]` and it returned nothing.